# error bad file descriptor while send on socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcpsocket

i am trying to send the data from server child processes to the clients.
i am storing first client fd in ids[0] and seconds one in ids[1]
then i am trying to send the data from first child process to another client and vic-e-versa.

i get bad file descriptor error.

```
//ids are defined at the begining as follows
    int *ids = (int *) mmap(NULL,5*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
//accept is in a for loop...
    mysocket = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
    printf("\nClient connected ...\n ");
    ids[i]=mysocket;
    i++;
    printf(" socket and id %d %d",mysocket,ids[i-1]);
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (mysocket < 0) {
            perror("Error in accept");
            exit(1);
        }

    do {

        fflush(stdout);
        //clearing the bufffer
        //memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf));
        //memset(buf, sizeof(buf), '\0');
        //reading message on the socket.
        if(i==1)
        if(send(ids[1], buf, 1024,0)==-1){
            perror("error in i=1");
                    printf("%d %d %d",mysocket,ids[0],ids[1]);
        }

        if(i==2) {
            if(send(ids[0], buf, 1024,0)==-1) {
                perror("error in i=2");
                printf("%d %d %d", mysocket, ids[0], ids[1]);
            }
        }

        if (strcmp(buf, "CLOSE") == 0) {
            close(mysocket);
            break;
        }

    } while (1);
```

Error i get :
error in i=1: Bad file descriptor
4 4 5

the values 4 and 5 are of the fds and that are correctly stored and i am not closing the sockets anywhere.

Comment: `i` isn't declared in your code

Comment: The error you describe means that one of the processes is trying to use a file descriptor number that does not correspond to an open file description *in that process*.  But your code does not comprise a complete or verifiable example that could reproduce the problem.  As a result, we can only guess about its nature.  Please edit the question to provide a [mcve], which will mean not only adding some bits but also modifying what you already have.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:: please consistently indent the code,  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.   Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: thanks you all for the suggestions. i am trying it with threads now to avoid shared memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is badly formatted and I hope I interpret it correctly.

```
ids[i]=mysocket;
i++;
```

If `i` was `0` then `ids[0]` is now valid, `ids[1]` is still invalid (i.e. has some arbitrary value which might look valid but is not) and `i` is now `1`. With `i==1` the child runs into this code (after proper formatting):

```
    if(i==1)
        if(send(ids[1], buf, 1024,0)==-1){
            perror("error in i=1");
            printf("%d %d %d",mysocket,ids[0],ids[1]);
       }
```

As you can see, it uses `send(ids[1]...`. But as explained above with `i==1` only `ids[0]` has a valid value and the value in `ids[1]` is invalid. Therefore the `send` fails with `Bad file descriptor`.

My guess is that you assume that a file descriptor created in the master process is actually valid in all child process since you are trying to use a shared array (with `MAP_SHARED`) between the childs and the master:

```
int *ids = (int *) mmap(NULL,5*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

But this assumption is wrong. File descriptors are not propagated into all child processes but only propagated on fork to the new child. This means your first child will have a valid file descriptor in `fds[0]` only while the second child will have a valid file descriptor in both `fds[0]` and `fds[1]`. **The fact that the first child will see the same file number in `fds[1]` as the second child due to the shared array does not mean that this file number is also associated with a valid (in-kernel) file descriptor.**

Note that it is very useful to actually document the intention of your code in your code. This way others can better understand your code and all (including you) can better verify if the intention actually matches the implementation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @Steffen
but the id[1] gets populated after a while and i can see the value while printing

Comment: @AshwinBhoyar: if `ids[1]` gets populated then `i` must be `>=2` since `i` is always one larger than the largest valid index in `ids[]` according to the code you've shown. But, the error you show happens with `i==1`.

Comment: @AshwinBhoyar: I think your actual problem is that you are assuming that that all file descriptors from the second child are valid file descriptors in the first child because you use a shared array. But even if the file numbers does not mean that there are file descriptors associated in the kernel with these file numbers. See edited post. And it would really help a lot if your code contains comments on what you are trying to do.